# How to make the custom reports read only for the portal users?

Tags: salesforce, report

I want to make custom report read only for all the customer portal users. I don't want to give them the permission to customize the report. I just want to show them the read only format of the report. Do anybody have solution?
I think we can do like dis..
Create and save the report, not with the current user, but with apex outside of the normal permission structure or with system user.

But here is the issue. I don't know how to do it.??

Any Solution??

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Folder(s) that contain the reports you want them to view does not have the sharing settings at "All Internal Users" group, by default Customer Portal Users will have Read Only access to the reports.  Changing the sharing settings on Report Folders to "All Internal Users" prevents Portal Users from viewing reports in that folder.  The Portal Users also need the "Run Reports" permission enabled.

Also, Portal Users can customize report results, so there should not be an issue regarding them modifying them.